# php paypal IPN doesn't work after upgrade

Tags: php, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

After security changes on Paypal Sandbox, my IPN listener doesn't work. 
I have upgraded php to **5.5.32** and curl to **7.47.0** using OpenSSL/1.0.1e

Here are my curls settings:

```php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 
          dirname(__FILE__)."/cert/cacert.pem");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $this->follow_location);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

if ($this->force_ssl_v3) {
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
}
```

Comment: The update on the sandbox was them deprecating older versions of SSL. Can you try: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);

Comment: As an added note: that security update has also now been made to live environments too.